# How do I remove space at the end of an output in C++?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, i;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i == 6 || i == 9)
            continue;
        cout << i << " ";

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Question- write 1 to n integer numbers but she do not write 6 and 9. you required to write a cpp program using "if" and "for" loop concepts and help to sakshi. Input Method: Get "n" which is the input number. Output Method: Print the integer value without 6 and 9.

TEST CASE 1:

```
INPUT
11
OUTPUT
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 10 11
```

My output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 10 11
```

I am getting one extra space after this 11 how to stop that? This program is printing one extra space in the output

Comment: if( i == 6 || i == 9 ) my bad

Comment: please properly format your code, especially your indentation.

Comment: The best option is to not write the space in the first place. There is no universal way to remove a character from a stream. You try sending a backspace, but that's not always respected or supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method @ user4581301 has mentioned

```
if (n > 0) std::cout << 1;

for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
{

    if( i == 6 || i == 9 )
        continue; 
  
    cout<<" " << i;
   
}
```